# Cocos2d-x and Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I'm very new to cocos2d-x development, and I also never built anything on Android.
I followed many text guides that seem to be outdated and not using Android Studio, but Eclipse instead as an IDE. I downloaded all required components (NDK, Ant, JDK), and I'm not sure where to use them in this IDE itself. When I built on iOS, my project worked just fine. When it was time to test it on Android, I followed this video guide http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLeGy1foMQA . My project kept crashing with "Unfortunately, projectname has stopped" message. Compiler never showed anything resembling an error report (or something that looks like one).

I'm very confused right now. Someone please give me a step-by-step guide on how to compile cocos2d-x projects on Android (I'm using a Mac).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a IDE to compile cocos2d-x projects on Android. You just have to use a command like:

```
cocos compile -s /your_cocos_project_path -p android -o /your_cocos_output_path
```

If you want to load your Android project in a IDE, you should have the following folders in your cocos2d-x project:

- proj.android
- proj.android-studio
- proj.ios_mac
- ...

For Eclipse you can import the project from proj.android folder and for Android Studio from proj.android-studio.

Then if you want to generate the apk from proj.android just execute the command that I wrote at the beginning. If you want to generate the apk from proj.android-studio, execute a command like:

```
cocos compile -s /your_cocos_project_path -p android --android-studio -o /your_cocos_output_path
```